# ImmutableJS find items that are not in both lists

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two list:

```
const list1 = List([1, 2, 3])
const list2 = List([2, 3])
```

What is the most efficient way to retrieve the item that is not on the second list? (In this case, it should be 1)

Comment: List is a function()?

Comment: Particularly, see @thefourtheye 's answer

Comment: @brk, List is a constructor, as the title says, I'm using ImmutableJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work ?

```js
let list1 = [1, 2, 3]
let list2 = [2, 3];
let result = list1.filter(function(a){
 return (!list2.includes(a));
});

console.log(result)
```

This is an optimized version of the above

```js
let list1 = [1, 2, 3]
let list2 = [2, 3];
let map = {};

for(let val of list2){
 map[val] = true;
}

let result = list1.filter(function(a){
 return map[a] != true;
});
console.log(result)
```